# Why "menus" unit is finalized too early?

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-2007, fastmm

I tested my application with FastMM and FullDebugMode turned on, since I had some shutdown problems.

After solving bunch of my own problems FastMM started to complain about calling virtual method  on a freed object in TPopupList. I tried to move the menus unit as early as possible in uses so that it would be finalized last, but it didn't help. Is this real problem, a bug in vcl or false alarm from FastMM?

Here's the full report from FastMM:

```
FastMM has detected an attempt to call a virtual method on a freed object. An access violation will now be raised in order to abort the current operation.

Freed object class: TPopupList

Virtual method: Offset +16

Virtual method address: 4714E4

The allocation number was: 220

The object was allocated by thread 0x1CC0, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
403216 [sys\system.pas][System][System.@GetMem][2654]
404A4F [sys\system.pas][System][System.TObject.NewInstance][8807]
404E16 [sys\system.pas][System][System.@ClassCreate][9472]
404A84 [sys\system.pas][System][System.TObject.Create][8822]
7F2602 [Menus.pas][Menus][Menus.Menus][4223]
40570F [sys\system.pas][System][System.InitUnits][11397]
405777 [sys\system.pas][System][System.@StartExe][11462]
40844F [SysInit.pas][SysInit][SysInit.@InitExe][663]
7F6368 [PCCSServer.dpr][PCCSServer][PCCSServer.PCCSServer][148]
7C90DCBA [ZwSetInformationThread]
7C817077 [Unknown function at RegisterWaitForInputIdle]

The object was subsequently freed by thread 0x1CC0, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
403232 [sys\system.pas][System][System.@FreeMem][2699]
404A6D [sys\system.pas][System][System.TObject.FreeInstance][8813]
404E61 [sys\system.pas][System][System.@ClassDestroy][9513]
428D15 [common\Classes.pas][Classes][Classes.TList.Destroy][2914]
404AB3 [sys\system.pas][System][System.TObject.Free][8832]
472091 [Menus.pas][Menus][Menus.Finalization][4228]
4056A7 [sys\system.pas][System][System.FinalizeUnits][11256]
4056BF [sys\system.pas][System][System.FinalizeUnits][11261]
7C9032A8 [RtlConvertUlongToLargeInteger]
7C90327A [RtlConvertUlongToLargeInteger]
7C92AA0F [Unknown function at towlower]

The current thread ID is 0x1CC0, and the stack trace (return addresses) leading to this error is:
4714B8 [Menus.pas][Menus][Menus.TPopupList.MainWndProc][3779]
435BB2 [common\Classes.pas][Classes][Classes.StdWndProc][11583]
7E418734 [Unknown function at GetDC]
7E418816 [Unknown function at GetDC]
7E428EA0 [Unknown function at DefWindowProcW]
7E428EEC [Unknown function at DefWindowProcW]
7C90E473 [KiUserCallbackDispatcher]
7E42B1A8 [DestroyWindow]
47CE31 [Controls.pas][Controls][Controls.TWinControl.DestroyWindowHandle][6857]
493BE4 [Forms.pas][Forms][Forms.TCustomForm.DestroyWindowHandle][4564]
4906D9 [Forms.pas][Forms][Forms.TCustomForm.Destroy][2929]

Current memory dump of 256 bytes starting at pointer address 7FF9CFF0:
2C FE 82 00 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 C4 A3 2D 0C 00 00 00 00 B1 D0 F9 7F
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 00 00 00 16 32 40 00 9D 5B 40 00 C8 5B 40 00
CE 82 40 00 3C 40 91 7C B0 B1 94 7C 0A 77 92 7C 84 77 92 7C 7C F0 96 7C 94 B3 94 7C 84 77 92 7C
C0 1C 00 00 32 32 40 00 12 5B 40 00 EF 69 40 00 BA 20 47 00 A7 56 40 00 BF 56 40 00 A8 32 90 7C
7A 32 90 7C 0F AA 92 7C 0A 77 92 7C 84 77 92 7C C0 1C 00 00 0E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C7 35 65 59
2C FE 82 00 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 38 CA 9A A6 80 80 80 80 80 80 00 00 00 00 51 D1 F9 7F
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C1 00 00 00 16 32 40 00 9D 5B 40 00 C8 5B 40 00
CE 82 40 00 3C 40 91 7C B0 B1 94 7C 0A 77 92 7C 84 77 92 7C 7C F0 96 7C 94 B3 94 7C 84 77 92 7C
,  þ  ‚  .  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  Ä  £  -  .  .  .  .  .  ±  Ð  ù  
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  À  .  .  .  .  2  @  .    [  @  .  È  [  @  .
Î  ‚  @  .  <  @  ‘  |  °  ±  ”  |  .  w  ’  |  „  w  ’  |  |  ð  –  |  ”  ³  ”  |  „  w  ’  |
À  .  .  .  2  2  @  .  .  [  @  .  ï  i  @  .  º     G  .  §  V  @  .  ¿  V  @  .  ¨  2    |
z  2    |  .  ª  ’  |  .  w  ’  |  „  w  ’  |  À  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  Ç  5  e  Y
,  þ  ‚  .  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  €  8  Ê  š  ¦  €  €  €  €  €  €  .  .  .  .  Q  Ñ  ù  
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  Á  .  .  .  .  2  @  .    [  @  .  È  [  @  .
Î  ‚  @  .  <  @  ‘  |  °  ±  ”  |  .  w  ’  |  „  w  ’  |  |  ð  –  |  ”  ³  ”  |  „  w  ’  |
```

I'm using Delphi 2007 and FastMM 4.97.

**Edit1:** I think the main problem here is why does Classes.StdWndProc call Menus.TPopupList? Digging the call stack inside debugger shows that System.FinalizeUnit is called three times, then it goes to SysUtils.ShowException, which tries to display MessageBox and after bunch of user32.dll calls we end up to classes.StdWndProc.

**Edit2:** I had problem with interfaces, fixing that made this problem go away. The object with interface was freed, but the reference was released later on. When the interface was released, occured an exception which I initially somehow ignored. Releasing the interface probably corrupted something which caused all other problems.

Answer (score 7):

That situation can happens when a unit finalize after another unit it indirectly depends on.

For exemple, take the following unit:

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  Contnrs;

var
  ItemHolder : TObjectList;

implementation

initialization
  ItemHolder := TObjectList.Create(True);
finalization
  ItemHolder.Free;
end.
```

That unit only directly depends on Contnrs. For that reason, delphi will ensure that this unit is finalized before Contnrs is. If the ObjectList contains TForms, Delphi won't ensure that Unit1 is finalized before unit Forms. If there are still some forms left while closing the application, TObjectList (Since it owns the object) will free the items it contains(Call TForm.Free).  But since Unit1 doesn't depends on TForm, it's possible that the unit Forms is already finalized and that TForm.Destroy isn't in memory anymore.

This is why you need to be very carefull about what you do in finalization sections.

I'm not sure it's the source of your problem, but I would look that way first.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen such problems with Delphi 2007 before. Sometimes the compiler gets confused and generates incorrect initialization or finalization order. Sadly, I was never able to create a reproducible test case to send to the CodeGear/Embarcadero people.

Whenever that happened, a full rebuild helped.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that FastMM4 is the FIRST line in your project file's uses clause (project|View source).  If its not there, then add it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like one of your forms is getting destroyed after Menus.pas has been finalized.  If your form has a menu on it, it would probably have to have Menus in its **uses** list in the **interface** section, which should make this impossible.

The only time I've seen issues like this pop up (no pun intended) is when using packages.  Are you perhaps using a DPK with a plugin that adds a popup menu or menu items to your program?  Package finalization can do some strange things to your program if you're not careful.

Either way, the solution is probably to dispose of the menu yourself before menus.pas finalizes.  When it's time for the program to shut down, call Free on your popup menu and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Yes, that was the point of the question, why menus.pas is finalized too early, before all forms have been finalized.

I'm not sure about the packages, I think there should be none of that kind, but I'll have to check.

Answer (score 0):

Update: this is only partial workaround

Workaround:
In main form of your application write

```
finalization
  FreeAndNil(PopupList);
end.
```

this free PopupList and set to nil, so PopupList.Free in menus.pas will be OK.